# ms sql error :Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'

Tags: sql-server, syntax

```
select * 
from other table inner join
(
select Count(*),
F1,F2,F3
from Table
group by F1,F2,F3
) on F1 = OtherF
```

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your subselect needs to be aliased:

```
select * 
from other AS o 
inner join ( select Count(*), F1,F2,F3 
             from Table 
             group by F1,F2,F3 ) AS x on F1 = o.OtherF
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to alias the subquery

```
select * from other table inner join ( select Count(*), F1,F2,F3 from Table group by F1,F2,F3 ) s on s.F1 = OtherF
```